# How can i check if my button is pressed or not in php if button type is not submit?

Tags: php, html, button

Here is my small section of code and please tell me what should be my "if" condition if i wanna check whether button is pressed or not in same page.

```
$id_update = "/dashboard/SAM/Ass3_update_page.php?id=".$row['Todo_id']."";
$id_delete = "/dashboard/SAM/Ass3_todo_page.php?id=".$row['Todo_id']."";
$onclick_update = "location.href = 'Ass3_update_page.php?id=".$row['Todo_id']."'";
$onclick_delete = "location.href = 'Ass3_todo_page.php?id=".$row['Todo_id']."'";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['Todo_id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Todo_managername']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Todo_workassign']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Todo_workdesc']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Todo_date']."</td>";
echo "<td><button name='update' type='button' onclick=".$onclick_update."><a href='".$id_update."'>Update</a></button></td>";
echo "<td><button name='delete type='button' onclick=".$onclick_delete."><a href='".$id_delete."'>Delete</a></button></td>";
```

Comment: the button is on the client, php runs on the server. unless your client notifies the server using javascript, i don’t see how the server could possibly get aware of a button being pressed

Comment: Well one obvious problem is that you have a button that has javascript triggered on click, that wraps a link that also goes to a URL. You should stick with one or the other. Then in your URL add a variable for something like **?action=update&id=** that way you have something to look for

Answer (score 0):

For `<buttons>` try this

```
 if($_POST['update']) {
    // Do something
    }
```